Do you get a sin for uploading video games that contains swearing
I'm a YouTuber who is uploading Left 4 Dead 2 Content. Left 4 Dead 2 is a zombie-shooting game action that contains swearing between playable characters. It also includes violence since we kill zombies and all. The swearing is a bit tough for smaller kids, but there aren't things such as dropping the f-bomb or using any other words of the sort. I don't swear but my character does, do I still get a sin for uploading video game content that contains swearing and is it haram to upload this type of content? If so, should I stop uploading L4D2 content and delete my videos? (Make sure to watch L4D2 Videos if you don't know it)
